# Can't shutdown a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown

I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 running latest release OS X. Recently when I am shutting down my computer it just get stuck in the spinner. So the only way is to force shut it down which might not be good for the computer. Do I have to reinstall the firmware or I can do something to help it? Thanks

Note that this doesn't happen when trying to shutdown in recovery mode.

Comment: I'd run the 'standard troubleshoot' first - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232100/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin I booted into safe mode and it fixed that problem once, but when I start normal boot, the spinner come again.

Comment: only 6 other steps to try then ;) though, seriously, you ought to do the safe boot again when you reach that step.

Comment: @Tetsujin The rest doesn't seems to help, just the safe boot fixed it once.

Comment: @TomShen is there a message about an app running when you try to shut down? Have you installed any apps recently (right around the time the problem starting occurring)?

Comment: @JohnRamos This happens even if I don't have any app other than Finder open. It even happens when I press shutdown from login window.

Comment: @TomShen try to recreate the issue and then check in Activity Monitor (the CPU section) to see what apps/processes might be active in background. You can post a photo via imgur or in your question and alert me to it down here.